# how to separate the value inside a list of list base on the length value of character?

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-re

The data is like this, Here need to divide the integer character based on length.

length should be 10, rest of the peace not important.

anyone please help.

```
list_val = [['01234567890000','123456789','xyz'],['123456789','1234567890111','abcdefghijkl']]

new_list = [[] for i in range(len(list_val))]
for i in range(Len(list_val)):
    for txt in list_val[i]:
        if len(txt)>10:
            new_list[i].append(re.split(r'(\d{10})', txt))
        else:
            new_list[i].append(txt)
```

output is:

```
[[['', '0123456789', '0000'], '123456789', 'xyz'],['123456789', ['', '1234567890', '111'], ['abcdefghijkl']]]
```

Here need to remove the inside list unnecessary parts.

desired output:

```
[['0123456789','123456789', 'xyz'],['123456789','1234567890', 'abcdefghijkl']]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to truncate the numerical strings, not split them. Just use slices for that:

```
new_list = [[s[:10] if s.isdigit() else s for s in sub] for sub in list_val]
# [['0123456789', '123456789', 'xyz'], ['1234567890', '123456789', 'abcdefghijkl']]
```